# VS2015 error C1026 - a compiler defect?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2015

So with C code that doesn't bother VS2013 and earlier at all, we are getting the following error with VS2015 (Update 1):

```
fatal error C1026: parser stack overflow, program too complex
```

The code is a bit iffy in that it uses **loads** -- I stopped counting beyond 200 -- of `if`-`else if` statements inside one outer `if`, inside a `while`-loop. The developer responsible for that piece of code is somewhat stuck in mid-1980s ways. But the project is fortunately only used for one internal tool.

Example (due to obvious misconceptions in comments and first answer):

```
while(whatever)
{
    if(some_condition)
    {
        if(condition1)
            do_something1();
        else if(condition2)
            do_something2();
        else if(condition3)
            do_something3();
        else if(condition4)
            do_something4(); /* more than two hundred more `else if` */
    }
}
```

Anyway, since the older versions of VS are not bailing on that code, am I to assume that this is a newly introduced compiler defect which I should report to Microsoft (e.g. via Connect)?

Comment: I would not call that a defect because it does not work with a new tool. Which C standard did you compile with before and which C standard does the new tool compile with?

Comment: All in all, it would be better if the developer responsible for that piece of code was somewhat fired.

Comment: ..and by 'fired', I don't mean summary loss of employment.  I was thinking in terms of a ropes, a stake, brushwood and flaming torches.

Comment: @Elyasin: did not specify a standard explicitly.

Comment: > 200 `if-else if` statements is maybe not very beautiful, but IMO it should compile. I'd report it to Microsoft.

Comment: Assuming nornal indentation, how many monitors side-by-side do you need to see all the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current C standard only guarantees 127 levels of nested blocks. The 1980s version of C only guaranteed 15 levels. Writing programs that aren't in accordance with the C standard is the core problem here.

Anyway, this seems to be a [confirmed bug in VS2015](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1572286/program-too-complex-used-to-compile-with-vs-2013-but-not-anymore).

Comment: It's strange, but I've never come up against this limit.